Is it correct to say that the gold foil experiment identified the nucleus’s volume relative to the atom?
In my studies, I came across the statement: “The volume of the nucleus relative to the atom can be identified using the gold foil experiment.” I’ve been considering whether this is accurate or misleading. Here’s my reasoning, and I’d like to know if there are any flaws in my logic.
From my understanding:

The gold foil experiment didn’t measure or calculate the nucleus’s volume relative to the atom. Instead, it primarily demonstrated that the atom is mostly empty space, which explains why most alpha particles pass through with minimal deflection.

The experiment led to the idea of a dense, small nucleus because a small fraction of alpha particles were deflected at large angles. This suggests a tiny, concentrated mass in the atom's center, not a direct comparison of volumes.

Atomic models by Thomson, Rutherford, and others were theoretical interpretations meant to make sense of the atom's structure rather than exact measurements or direct comparisons of different parts of the atom.


Given these points, I’m concluding that the statement is incorrect. The gold foil experiment suggested that the nucleus is small relative to the atom but didn’t directly identify or quantify the relative volume of the nucleus compared to the atom.
Does my reasoning make sense, or am I missing something fundamental here?

It measures probability of diffraction of alpha particles as the function of alpha energy and the foil thickness. From that, and from gold density and molar mass, there is calculated the effective Au atom diameter and nucleus cross-section, From that, there is calculated estimation of the ratio atom diameter/nucleus diameter.

How do you "identify" volume? That's what's wrong in you sentence. The volume was estimated and indeed measured, no matter how imprecisely.

To close voter - OP has provided their thoughts on the statement and asked if there are any flaws in the logic.  How is it unclear or need more clarity?

@NilayGhosh Well, two CV now and likely there's gonna be more. This is some lame semantics all over again. Not about the experiment (which wasn't terribly chemical itself) but what does measure mean, or maybe that we shouldn't use "identify" instead? Whatever...

The Rutherford total scattering cross section is infinite, since the Coulomb force that causes it never goes to zero.

Here the word "identified" word appears for e.g if there water in glass you can identify whether there is water in the glass or not, if there water in the glass you can measure it up say 183ml or wharever

Another question how this experimenters said  alpha particles goes and collide with the Au foil come in the same direction by gaining 180 degrees turn. then how their apparatus was?
